# using extended regular expressions in sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to do some crazy regular expressions in sed but am not allowed to

Am I just not getting regular expressions or are regular expressions different in sed

The file I"m working with is like

```
46,uie,ieo
39,ieu,tii
44-46,yut,til
45,dkd,ytu
65,dkd,ytu
40-45,dkd,ytu
```

When I do

```
cat text.txt | sed s/^4[0-9],//g
```

I almost get what I want, I get

```
uie,ieo
39,ieu,tii
44-46,yut,til
dkd,ytu
65,dkd,ytu
40-45,dkd,ytu
```

But I want to get rid of the of one's that are like 40-45 and 44-46
So I've tried

```
cat text.txt | sed s/^4[0-9](-4[0-9])?,//g 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

And when I try

```
cat text.txt | sed s/^4[0-9]-?4?[0-9]?,//g
```

I just get

```
46,uie,ieo
39,ieu,tii
44-46,yut,til
45,dkd,ytu
65,dkd,ytu
40-45,dkd,ytu
```

So nothing is filtered

Thank-you!

Comment: Escape your parentheses with a backslash, like so: `cat test | sed -r s/^4[0-9]\(-4[0-9]\)?,//g`.

Comment: it's csv file with 3 columns, you want to remove the first column, use `cut`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: He apparently doesn't want to remove the first column unless it's in the range 40 to 49.

Comment: @KeithThompson: you are right, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cat text.txt | sed s/^4[0-9](-4[0-9])?,//g
```

Two problems.

First, you need to quote the argument to `sed`. It contains metacharacters that are recognized by the shell, such as `(` and `?`; you need to quote the argument so the shell treats it as just a string and doesn't try to interpret it.

```
cat text.txt | sed 's/^4[0-9](-4[0-9])?,//g' # this still doesn't work
```

Second, `sed` doesn't use extended regular expressions by default.  If you're using GNU sed (type `sed --version` to confirm this), you can use the `-E` option to enable extended regular expressions:

```
cat text.txt | sed -E 's/^4[0-9](-4[0-9])?,//g'
```

or you can use backslashes to let `sed` recognize the `(`, `)`, and `?` characters:

```
cat text.txt | sed 's/^4[0-9]\(-4[0-9]\)\?,//g'
```

Finally, this is a [Useless Use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).  `sed` is perfectly capable of reading input either from stdin or from a specified file; you don't need to feed it its input via a pipe from `cat`:

```
sed 's/^4[0-9]\(-4[0-9]\)\?,//g' text.txt
```

The `-E` option is specified by POSIX; I think this was a relatively recent addition.  GNU sed has supported `-E` since 2006 (for originally compatibility with BSD sed), but it's not currently documented in any released version.  Documentation was added in 2013, but the most recent official release of GNU sed was 4.2.2, in 2012.

**UPDATE 2021-11-08**: It does *not* appear that POSIX specifies the `-E` option (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), though it has been proposed.

The manual for version 4.7 of GNU sed says:

```
'-E'
'-r'
'--regexp-extended'
     Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular
     expressions.  Extended regexps are those that 'egrep' accepts; they
     can be clearer because they usually have fewer backslashes.
     Historically this was a GNU extension, but the '-E' extension has
     since been added to the POSIX standard
     (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use '-E' for
     portability.  GNU sed has accepted '-E' as an undocumented option
     for years, and *BSD seds have accepted '-E' for years as well, but
     scripts that use '-E' might not port to other older systems.  *Note
     Extended regular expressions: ERE syntax.
```

The manual links to [this entry](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528) in the Austin Group Defect Tracker, which lists the issue as "Resolved => Applied" as of 2020-03-18. Perhaps it just hasn't been applied to the opengroup.org web site.

Comment: `-E` instead of `-r` is more portable.

Comment: "The `-E` option is specified by POSIX; I think this was a relatively recent addition."
Are you sure about this?  It's nowhere in `man 1p sed`.

Comment: @ban_javascript No, I'm not entirely sure. See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F, '!/^4[0-9]\>/;{print $2,$3}' text.txt
```

details:

```
!/^4[0-9]\>/ # returns 1 (true) when the line doesn't start with a number between
             # 40 and 49 ( `\>` figures a boundary )
             # (when the expression returns true, the whole line is printed and 
             # awk jumps to the next line)

{print $2,$3} # otherwise fields 2 and 3 are printed
```

`-F,` defines the field delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple of basic UNIX things you're getting wrong.  Those arguments to `sed` need to be quoted.  They are being interpreted by the shell as file name globs.  Also, that's an extraneous use of cat, you can get the same affect (and more efficiently), just by using the shell redirection `<`.  Also, in `sed` regexps, the `()` and `?` are normal chars unless escaped with `\`.  So the result is this which works for me:

```
sed 's/^4[0-9]\(-4[0-9]\)\?,//g' < text.txt
```