# Replace a value of attribute in json in SQL dump

Tags: mysql, json, regex, shell, sed

I have table in mariadb with five columns and in that one column is of type longtext (Compressed String) in json format.
Also I have a dump of that table and in that I need to change the attribute salary value in nested json string in below based on the value of empId attribute's value.

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1,"ram","1243","19-03-14",{"name":"ram",age:"23","empId":"1234","address":{"city":{"name":"",.*},"country":{"name":"",.*}},"gender":"male","hobbies":"travel","salary":"40000","qualification":"BE","marrital-status":"married",.*),
(2,"komal","1243","19-03-14",{"name":"komal",age:"21","empId":"1534","address":{"city":{"name":"",.*},"country":{"name":"",.*}},"gender":"male","hobbies":"music","salary":"30000","qualification":"BE","marrital-status":"married",.*),
(3,"ramya","1243","19-03-14",{"name":"ramya",age:"22","empId":"1754","address":{"city":{"name":"",.*},"country":{"name":"",.*}},"gender":"male","hobbies":"travel","salary":"40000","qualification":"BE","marrital-status":"married",.*),
(4,"raj","1243","19-03-14",{"name":"raj",age:"23","empId":"1364","address":{"city":{"name":"",.*},"country":{"name":"",.*}},"gender":"male","hobbies":"playing","salary":"40000","qualification":"BE","marrital-status":"married",.*);
```

I have a csv file with empId and mapped to revised salary.
I will loop the csv file and in the dump based on empId replace the salary from the csv.
I tried with sed command to replace with below pattern.

```
:%s/\("empId":"1243"\),\(.*\),\("address":{"city":{\),\(.*\),\(}\),\("country":{\),\(.*\),\(}}\),\(.*\),"salary":[0-9\"]*/\1,\2,\3,\4,5,\6,\7,\8,\9,"salaray":"50000"/
```

but I am getting below error message.

```
E872: (NFA regexp) Too many '('
E51: Too many \(
E476: Invalid command
```

How can I parse the json in the dump and change the value using sed or any other way in shell script?

Comment: This is common text-processing question not relative to MySQL and/or JSON.

Comment: Why you do not want to import your data then alter it with simple SQL query?

Comment: You used a Vim command with sed.

Comment: What do you mean by "compressed string"?  JSON can only handle UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about your use case but you can try this for each empId in the csv.

> sed -E 's/"empId":"1234+"/"salary":1234/g' input.txt

Add a -i to the command to replace the text in the file otherwise it will just be the standard output that changes after you test that it's working.

Using node or python to do this might be easier. You could make a small script that reads the json from a file then outputs the new json to a new file. Or if you're restricted in your tech stack, maybe loading the csv into the sql db itself and creating a query from it, with your input data, to get the right form to then insert could be another option.

Some resources I used which might explain better than this short answer.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-string-in-files/

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/grep-regex

[using extended regular expressions in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277236/using-extended-regular-expressions-in-sed)